# Factorial calculation between multiplying numbers and using math.factorial

Tags: python, factorial

I recently had to calculate a problem that includes permutation, and so factorial, in Python.
When P(n, m) = n!/(n-m)!, I had to calculate P(24, 23) * P(31, 18)

1. My initial attempt was to use the "factorial" function from "math"

```
from math import factorial

res = factorial(24) / factorial(24 - 23) * factorial(31) / factorial(31 - 18)
print(int(res))
```

This gave me 819307862388221490258228866079033329420993560576, but this wasn't the answer to the problem.

2. My second attempt was to simply multiply all the numbers

```
res = 1
for i in range((24 - 23 + 1), (24 + 1)):
    res *= i
for i in range((31 - 18 + 1), (31 + 1)):
    res *= i
print(res)
```

This gave me 819307862388221633448919424563251511296000000000, which was accepted as the answer.

I didn't think the factorial function gave me the wrong result, so I assumed the difference was due to the way python calculates big numbers, or due to the last integer conversion.

But I wasn't really sure what I needed to search for, so I came here.

Can someone tell me why such difference in calculation result occurs?
Or what I should be searching for to get the answer to my question?

Comment: Side note: use `math.perm`

Comment: @KellyBundy I didn't know their was such function. Feel kind of dumb not looking for it in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Division using `/` yields a `float` in python, even if both operands are integers. Floats can't represent all numbers exactly, so you get the wrong result from the operation.

To use integer division, use the `//` operator:

```
res = factorial(24) // factorial(24 - 23) * factorial(31) // factorial(31 - 18)
# gives res = 819307862388221633448919424563251511296000000000
```

Comment: Thanks! // did it. Thanks also for the link